# Link for same page

Tags: php, html

Longtime reader of stackoverflow but second question.

This is what i am doing

```
echo "<td><a  href = 'http://localhost/map/index.php'  
value='$id'  >Delete</a></td>";
```

This is what we do when we use submit button

```html
<?php 
echo  "<body style='background-color:gray'>";
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){ 
include("connection.php");
 echo " <table id='t01'  border='20px solid black'      width='100%' >";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th> DETAILS ABOUT DELETION</th>"; 
 echo "<td>DELETED SUCCESSFULLY </td></tr>";
$id = $_POST["submit"];
$select1="DELETE FROM app  where  id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($select1);
if ($conn->query($result)==true){
 echo "<td>DELETED SUCCESSFULLY </td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
//echo "DELETED SUCCESSFULLY";
}



?>
```

I just want to do something like that * without using input type=submit* ..... But dont know how to do 
Any advice will be appreciated ... Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to reference the current script.  Use `print_r($_SERVER)` to see all the available data.

Comment: ^ The title and the question don't match at all. That comment is answering the title, not the question.

Comment: where should i  use this ?

Comment: If you want to achieve that you may use javascript with php

Comment: What you're looking for is Ajax.

Answer (score 2):

firstly pass the id in the url like so:

```
echo "<td><a  href = 'http://localhost/map/index.php?id=$id'>Delete</a><td>";
```

then check it with:

```
if (isset ($_GET['id'])){
...
```

you basically swapping POST for GET

Comment: you still do, you submit to the same page, it just adds the id to the url which you then use to decide what to delete

Comment: 'http://localhost/map/index.php?id=$id' using this link  it will go to index.php?id=*something* ... is there any solution of this problem ?

Comment: that is still `index.php` regardless of anything after the `?`

Comment: i think index.php is not the same as index.php?id=*somethng* ....Is not that so ?

Comment: it is the same page to the webserver

Comment: anything after the `?` is called the `query string` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: @Dagon your patience and perseverance are inspiring.

Comment: @zeeshansarfraz please read this, http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers i see you haven't accepted other answers for precious questions which you can and should go back and do.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang SO distracts me nicely from my paid job ;)